# How can I test if I am allowed to force push?

Tags: git, git-rebase

If I want to edit a past commit which was already pushed to a remote, how can I test if I am allowed to force push without actually changing anything?

To edit a past commit I usually use `git rebase -i HEAD~N` and then change `pick` to `edit` where I want to make changes.
If I do this and realize afterwards that I am not allowed to force push, I need to reset my workspace (which I want to avoid, because the changes I made to the commit will be lost).

I know that it might be bad practise to do this with already pushed commits.

Is there a way to test this before I actually do a rebase?

Comment: Why would "the changes I made to the commit" be lost? You can create a branch pointing to it before the reset.

Comment: Yes this seems to work, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only completely-reliable test for whether you have permission to do *X* (for some arbitrary *X*, often not even Git-related) is to attempt to do *X* and see if it succeeds.  The fundamental problem with "test if *X* is allowed, then do *X*" is that the answer could change in between the test and the attempt.  (Some systems *do* support ask-permission-first reliably, but most don't: most give you an answer that expires by the time you get it.)

That said, Git's force-push permissions are determined by the *other* Git, and there's no way to ask it other than to try it anyway!  The closest you can come to asking the other Git is to ask the other system *about* its Git, in some other-system-specific way.  Your best bet might be to create a temporary branch, force-push to it, then delete it.  If the force-push step succeeds, then you know that you at least had permission to force-push to that one branch for that one moment.

Since common host sites like GitHub allow administrators to "lock" or "protect" some particular branch(es).  The details of how this works, and who has what permission, are up to those hosting sites.  [Here is the GitHub page on their branch restriction options.](https://help.github.com/articles/about-branch-restrictions/)